# How to open a new terminal, execute a process in that terminal and pipe to the process?

Tags: window, redirect, pager

What I'd like to do basically is a new-window version of `less`. Long ago there was a tool called `gless` which did exactly that. For example

```
cat my_very_long_file | gless
```

would open a new window and run a `less`-like pager showing my very long file; the terminal from which I launch the command would stay clean.

`gless` is not available in newer systems. The closest alternative I found is `gview -` (practically `gvim` in read-only mode, reading standard input) but this isn't the exact thing; it reads in the whole stdin before displaying anything, so isn't good for large inputs.

I thought of running a new terminal (`xterm`, `konsole` or anything) with `less` as the initial command. But it doesn't work the way I want; I would like to do something like

```
cat my_very_long_file | xterm -e less
```

But xterm and all other terminals don't seem to pass their standard input to the process they run - the new window opens, but disappears immediately.

(I know I can start the command in the new terminal; but it's not what I want. I really want to run a command in the current shell and redirect to a new process. `cat` is just an example.)

As a test of any suggested method, please consider this as a test case:

```
od -a /dev/random | <whatever-solution>
```

With the solution substituted, this should create a new window with a pager (or any other program for that matter) that receives an endless random stream of text.

(Late addition) I am looking for a simple solution that will keep the spirit of piping to a pager. Multi-step solutions can work but are unnatural. There is a single command line that also works: `xterm -e 'whatever | less'`, I use it sometimes but it is unnatural for me.

Answer (score 2):

How about a named pipe?

```
mkfifo /tmp/test.fifo
od -a /dev/urandom > /tmp/test.fifo
```

And in the new window:

```
cat /tmp/test.fifo | less
```

Or:

```
gnome-terminal -e "bash -c 'cat /tmp/test.fifo | less'"
```

Comment: Sorry, this is not what I was looking for. I want to have the convenience of a simple pipeline to a pager, much like using `less`. Using two or three commands to achieve that is not natural.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this funcation to your ~/.bashrc:

```
gless() { gnome-terminal -e "less $*" & }
```

This starts the terminal in the background, freeing your console. Also it passes all arguments to the less command (e.g. gless -S test.txt)